# Windows Vista - Can Boot into Safe Mode Command Prompt, Cannot Access Flash Drive

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Hey there,

Got a laptop dropped into my lap. Has Vista installed. Normal boot never gets past the login screen. Safe mode will get past, but just barely. I can try and start the task manager at that point, but it never opens.

Only reliable way to do anything I've got is the safe mode command prompt... Boots up and logs in fine. I can't see anything noticably wrong via regedit, but it's been a long time since I've had to fix up a Windows box... not sure that I would.

Problem I'm having, is that I want to run ComboFix/etc, but have no way to get them on there... When I pop a flash drive in, it seems to mount it (flash drive flickers as normal) but it never seems to be mounted... I cannot access it through any drive letter on the command line.

I managed to start the device manager (devmgmt.msc) and the flash drive was recognized and listed...

Any ideas on how to get this thing going again? (Short of a reinstall.)

(It has no CD drive, either, so burning files to CD would not be easy...)

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a reinstall of Vista or another OS? All the issues seem to be completely software related, and frankly not being able to get past the login screen is just weird. Vista should be doing all that stuff on it's own.

Did you check msconfig i believe it is to see what programs are starting on boot and if the normal boot sequence is set?

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot into command-mode and Task Manager, then maybe you can also check the system by using "sfc /scannow".

However, if it is at all possible that the computer suffers from a virus infection, then format and re-install is the best solution.

Also, because of the possibility that the hard disk is corrupted, it's better to do a full format (not quick format) while re-installing Windows.